# Como pegar os dados de uma tabela e passar em uma View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Fiz esta Action e preciso mandar para uma View quando for criar um internamento preciso colocar qual paciente internar.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Você colocou uma imagem do código e/ou mensagem de erro. Apesar de parecer uma boa ideia, não é! Um dos motivos é que se alguém quiser responder a pergunta, não pode copiar o código e alterar algo dentro. Clique no link [edit] e **coloque o código/erro como texto**. Veja mais sobre isso nesses links - [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/3774), [Postar mensagem de erro como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7816/3774)

Comment: Você já está enviando, pela ViewBag... mas o ideal seria utilizar uma ViewModel